# Selenium: How to send keys to a JQuery input using Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests

I have been unsuccessful in sending keys to a JQuery input. I'm trying automate login on this site and their login is a Prettyphoto JQuery lightbox popup. Nothing I've tried works.

This is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pp_full_res\"]/div/form/p[1]/input")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pp_full_res\"]/div/form/p[2]/input")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"prettyPhotoLogin\"]")).click();
```

Something else I tried but still did not work is:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
executor.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('username').value='username'");
```

The page is http://www.besthorrormovielist.com/ and the login link is located on the footer.

EDIT:
I'm able to click on the login link on the footer and open the login JQuery popup but Selenium does not see the username and password input fields within the JQuery popup.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The **`Login`** link is located on the footer which is not within the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) when **`Selenium`** opens the page. We need to bring the intended `WebElement` within the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) to interact with it, click the element to open the **`Login`** form and then try to invoke **`sendKeys("username")`** method as follows:

```
WebElement myelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='footerbottom']//a[@href='#loginform']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", myelement); 
myelement.click();
```

Comment: Hello DebajanB thanks for your response but the above code did not work. I'm able to open the JQuery login popup but I cannot send keys to the username and password inputs within the login popup. When I check to see if Selenium sees the name and password input fields I get Element not visible.